# Picasso android Target must not be null

Tags: android, listview, picasso

I am pretty new to android studio and still learning from video tutorials. I found Picasso and want to use it for my project but when i tried to apply/practice in a listview i dont seem to get it, im having an error that say `Target must not be null`. Ive tried the solutions around but still nothing. Sorry for my bad english. here is my code please help me.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int row_layout, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout2, values);
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageHolder holder = null; 
    holder = new ImageHolder();

    LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout2, parent, false);
    String tvShow = getItem(position);

    TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    theTextView.setText(tvShow);

    holder.imageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    Picasso.with(this.context).load(getItem(R.drawable.sample4)).into(holder.imageIcon); //ERROR HERE

    return theView;
}

static class ImageHolder
{
    ImageView imageIcon;
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static class ImageHolder {
    ImageView imageIcon;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] favoriteShows = {
            "Hannibal", "Sherlock", "Supernatural"
    };

    //ImageHolder holder = new ImageHolder();

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, favoriteShows);

    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);

    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String tvShowPicked= "You selected " +
                    String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvShowPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Ive alse tried to put the Picasso lines in MainActivity to see if anything changes.

```
 holder.imageIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.sample4)
            .into(holder.imageIcon);
```

My row_layout2.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sample3"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="left|bottom"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="ADDRESS HERE">
</TextView>
```

my activity_main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/theListView">

    </ListView>
```

Error Log:

```
06-29 21:06:13.990    1288-1288/com.erlawkward.albarol.listviewexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erlawkward.albarol.listviewexample/com.erlawkward.albarol.listviewexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)

at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)

at com.erlawkward.albarol.listviewexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
```

Method)

Comment: Post the code of layout file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adapter replace

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load(getItem(R.drawable.sample4)).into(holder.imageIcon);
```

with

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.sample4).into(holder.imageIcon);
```

> Edit

Also you are using the `ViewHolder` pattern in a wrong way. The whole point of using it is to avoid inflating layouts every time `getView` is called. I edited the method as follow

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout2, parent, false);

        holder = new ImageHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.imageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ImageHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText(getItem(position));

    //ERROR FIXED
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.sample4).into(holder.imageIcon); 

    return convertView;
}
```

The Holder

```
static class ImageHolder
{
    ImageView imageIcon;
    TextView textView;
}
```

And onCreate in Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] favoriteShows = {
            "Hannibal", "Sherlock", "Supernatural"
    };

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout2, favoriteShows);

    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);
    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String tvShowPicked = "You selected " +
                    String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvShowPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Still having the same error. my holder.imageIcon is null and i dont know why.

Comment: @ErlAl Have you replace the `getView` method of yours with mine??, Also check that the error is the same in both scenarios

Comment: yes sir, i have replaced it and still having the same error.

Comment: @ErlAl I tested with your layout and works just fine, please post the logs and errors

Comment: posted the logs.. sorry i dont know how to edit right in the post.

Comment: @ErlAl remove the Picasso code in the method `onCreate`

Comment: @ErlAl Check the `onCreate` method on my answer.

Comment: it worked!, thanks alot sir.. i have an additional questions.

so what really happened there? 

and if using picasso, can i resize all image of any size in to square without cropping it?

Comment: @ErlAl Yes yo can, check `resize` method

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your `context` is null.

Try to initialize your context.

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int row_layout, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout2, values);
    this.context=context;
}
```

Comment: Still having the same error. 

Picasso.with(this.context).load(getItem(R.drawable.sample4)).into(holder.imageIcon);

the value in my .into() is still null

Comment: @omainegra's answer should solve your problem and if not then there might be id mismatching with your layout.I mean to say imageView1 might not exist in row_layout2.xml file .Please double check it.

Comment: here is my imageview

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample3"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

Comment: @ErlAl Please post the layout in your question, all of it

Comment: If this answer didn't fix your issue see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790301/picasso-illegalargumentexception-target-must-not-be-null

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Picasso for loading a drawable into an ImageView? 
Just use the **setImageResource()** method of the ImageView.

Comment: I have tried using it and use different image sizes but so far i did not like the output. 

I want all my images that i put to be in the same size and proportional to the device. if you can help me or give me a tip, please