# Get image into ImageView dynamically

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-layout, android-studio

> What my program is currently doing , it searches in a database for
>   an  ID(inputed by the user),  and based on that it displays the title,
>   and the respective "picture.jpg"(which is just a string).
>
> What I want to do, is I want to take the string(picture.jpg), and use 
>   that to search on the server. So in the end it should be something
>   like:
>
> ```
>     http://192.168.1.254/images/picture.jpg. And it should also display the picture.
>
>
>     SecondActivity.java
>
>     This is how my whole code looks like:
>
>     package br.exemplozxingintegration;
>
>     import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
> import android.app.ProgressDialog; 
> import android.content.ClipData; 
> import android.content.ClipboardManager; 
> import android.media.Image; 
> import android.os.Bundle; 
> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
> import android.view.View; 
> import android.widget.Button; 
> import android.widget.EditText; 
> import android.widget.ImageView; 
> import android.widget.TextView; 
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
>     import com.android.volley.RequestQueue; 
> import com.android.volley.Response; 
> import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
>  import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest;
>  import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
>  import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
>  import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
>
>     import org.json.JSONArray;
>  import org.json.JSONException; 
> import org.json.JSONObject;
>
>
>
>     public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
>
>
>
>         private EditText  pastetext;
>         private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
>         private ClipData myClip;
>         private Button btn;
>         private EditText textView1;
>         private Button buttonGet;
>         private TextView textViewResult;
>         private ImageView ImageView1;
>
>         private ProgressDialog loading;
>
>
>               @Override
>               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
>                   myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
>                   pastetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>                   btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPaste);
>                   btn.performClick();
>
>
>
>
>                   textView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>                   buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
>                   textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
>                   Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
>
>                   buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
>
>               }
>
>
>
>               @SuppressLint("NewApi")
>               public void paste(View view) {
>                   ClipData cp = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
>                   ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0);
>                   String text = item.getText().toString();
>                   pastetext.setText(text);
>                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Pasted",
>                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>
>               }
>
>
>         private void getData() {
>             String qrcode = textView1.getText().toString().trim();
>             if (qrcode.equals("")) {
>                 Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 return;
>             }
>             loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);
>
>             String url = Config.DATA_URL+textView1.getText().toString().trim();
>
>             StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onResponse(String response) {
>                     loading.dismiss();
>                     showJSON(response);
>                 }
>             },
>                     new Response.ErrorListener() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>                             Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                         }
>                     });
>
>             RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
>             requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
>         }
>
>         private void showJSON(String response){
>             String title="";
>             String image = "";
>             try {
>                 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
>                 JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
>                 JSONObject androidData = result.getJSONObject(0);
>                 title = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_TITLE);
>                 image = androidData.getString(Config.KEY_IMAGE);
>             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             textViewResult.setText("Title:\t" + title);//+"\nImagine :\t"+ image);
>             //int id = getResources().getIdentifier("http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/uploads/images/sm/"
>     + image, null, null);
>             //ImageView1.setImageURI(id);
>             Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.1.254/2015/380panel/uploads/images/sm/"
>     + image).into(ImageView1);
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             getData();
>         } }
>
>
>
>      // }
> ```

Comment: use image loader libraries to load uri images into imageview. Libraries like Glide,Picasso can be helpful

Comment: I know what about the libraries. But my question is how can i add the string at the of the link?

Comment: use [universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

Easy with Picasso Library:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.1.254/images/sm/" + image").into(ImageView1);       //where image is my string. And it says " Illegal line end ins tring literal"

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load("192.168.1.254/images/sm/" + image").into(ImageView1);  (without semicolon)

Comment: And yes, like @Rahul said, add the dependency to the gradle

Comment: Thx for noticing my mistake

Comment: I get this error on the Picasso line. "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790301/picasso-illegalargumentexception-target-must-not-be-null

ImagView is null, initialize it

Comment: What do you mean by initializing? I uploaded my code, for easier reviews

Comment: Your variable ImageView1 is not instanced.
 Image imageView1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); and var names in lower case ^^

Answer (score 0):

Picasso Library: http://square.github.io/picasso/

> Add this to gradle file in dependency :

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

> After add this library, try loading image url like this.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("<Any Image URL>").into(imageView);
```

Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are alreadu using volley , no need to use Picasso.Volley provides you with a NetworkImageView.Simply replace your ImageView in xml with `com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView` and in code just use

```
NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.setImageUrl("your url");
```