# Picasso "Target must not be null" (using Firebase database)

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso

I made a Firebase database with links (these are links to my Storage with some images)

[image]

The Storage:

[image]

I try  to connect to my database and get the value of ***Page_1*** for example by pushing a button

```
 private DatabaseReference mRef;

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chapters").child("Chapter 1").child("Page_1");

                mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String value = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());

                        textView.setText(value);
                        Picasso.get().load(value).into(page_holder);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

But when I run my app there is an exception and Picasso line says that:

> Target must not be null.

If I remove my picasso and only *place value of Page_1 into textView* it shows the correct value (*so it means that I actually get my value and it is not null*)

[image]

(sorry for the black pattern, I think that the lines might contain something important like a name of database (most likely not but I am a noob in stuff like that))

**PS**
The one thing I noticed is that when I get my value of Page_1 into TextView there is a *little delay* there. So I guess that Picasso is trying to get "Target" before it is loaded.
I tried to make something like a checker

```
String value_from_database = textView.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value_from_database)){
                       textView.setText("Image is loading|Doesn't exist");
                    }
                    else {
                        Picasso.get().load(value_from_database).into(page_holder);
                    }
```

But I still fail. And Picasso shows the same exception/error.

Please, tell me how can I solve it?

Comment: have you initialised `page_holder` ImageView

Comment: It looks like `page_holder` is not initialized. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790301/picasso-illegalargumentexception-target-must-not-be-null, which is the first result I get when searching for [picaso Target must not be null](https://www.google.com/search?q=picasso+Target+must+not+be+null.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says:

> "Target must not be null."

This means that in your case, the target is the `page_holder`, which is `null`. It has nothing to do with the code that you are using to get the data from the database, which is correct.

To solve this, please make sure you initialize your `page_holder` object so it cannot be `null` and you can use `Picasso` correctly.

Comment: Yeah it helped, thank you a lot. I really made a mistake with some names in my layout.

Answer (score 0):

This means that page_holder is null.